# How to enable Stay awake in the developer options using ADB?

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to find a way to enable the *Developer options* -> *Stay awake* option via ADB.
The solution that I found was to find a way to open developers option menu and then enable stay awake option using setevent command in ADB.

Now I'm trying to find the command that will open the developers options.
I found the command that opens display options:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.DisplaySettings
```

So I think that a similar command that opens developers options exists.

I will also be glad to hear about another way to enable stay awake option via ADB if there is any.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.DevelopmentSettings
```

Comment: your way is a little cleaner then mine :)

Comment: The command does not work on my Android 9 device (Sony). `Activity class {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.DevelopmentSettings} does not exist.`

Answer (score 23):

You can enable *Stay awake* option without having to use UI with the following command:

```
adb shell settings put global stay_on_while_plugged_in 3
```

Comment: Where is this settings database stored?

Comment: Its stored in /data/system/user/0/settings_global.xml

Comment: found it was missing an "s" on "user" - /data/system/users/0/settings_global.xml

Comment: Then how do disable it?

Comment: @Glorin Set value to 0 to disable it: https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN

Answer (score 6):

OK, I found a way:

```
adb shell am start -S com.android.settings/.Settings\$DevelopmentSettingsActivity
```

I used this : https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml

to find the name of the Activity I needed.

Now I have to figure out how to choose the stay awake option by createing a touch event or something...

Answer (score 3):

Set the 'keep awake while plugged in' setting.

```
adb shell svc power stayon true
```

Comment: This work on my RedMi Note 5 (Android 9) device, thanks.

Comment: Works on Android 11 (Sony Xperia 10 iii). The 'Stay awake' slider in the 'Developer options' menu changes when this command is issued (from the PC).

Comment: To check the state of the setting, use `adb shell dumpsys power | grep 'mStayOn='`

Comment: When toggling `mStayOn`, also other settings under `adb shell dumpsys power` change. From my expierience they are `mStayOnWhilePluggedInSetting`, `mUserActivitySummary` and `mLastSleepReason`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I know it is not what MiSo was asking but I think it may be relevant, I have created an app that will enable/dissable this 'Stay awake' setting as you connect/disconnect ADB.
The code is available open-source here: [ABD-Stay_Awake](https://github.com/projectdelta6/ADB-Stay-Awake#adb-stay-awake)

Answer (score -3):

try this:

```
setprop persist.sys.usb.config mtp,adb
```