# Turn off screen / display using ADB, but keep device in state mWakefulness=Awake

Tags: android, adb, screen

I want to turn the screen off, but keep the device awake without root, so that the foreground app stays awake. I have an app that achieves this using the proximity sensor to turn the screen off.

I've now tried:

```
adb shell settings put global stay_on_while_plugged_in 3
adb shell input keyevent 26
```

But when I check: 
    adb shell dumpsys power

the state changes to mWakefulness=Asleep. Can I do whatever the app is doing over ADB somehow?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18276941/1778421

Comment: I've tried your suggestion @AlexP. but it doesn't seem to do what I hoped. Question updated.